# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' during initialization

Tags: c++

**header**

```
struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

enum Department
{
    Game, 
    FrontEnd, 
    Backend, 
    Operation, 
    HumanResource
};

class Employee
{
    protected:
        int id;
        string name;
        char gender;
        Date entry_date;
        string post;
        Department dept;
        int salary;

    public:
        Employee();
        Employee(int id, const string& name, char gender, const Date& entry_date, string post, Department dept);
        virtual ~Employee();
};

class Manager : public Employee
{
    private:
        int num_staff;
        Employee** staffs;

    public:
        Manager();
        Manager(int id, const string& name, char gender, const Date& entry_date, Department dept);
        ~Manager();
};
```

**cpp**

```
Manager::Manager(int id, const string &name, char gender, const Date &entry_date, Department dept) : Employee(id, name, gender, entry_date, post, dept), num_staff(0), staffs(NULL) {}
```

The program crashes here with complaint **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc**

```
    Manager *pm1 = new Manager(101, "Bruce Wayne", 'M', Date{2016, 05, 10}, HumanResource);
```

I've spent tons of time solving it but failed.
Anyone can help? thx in advance.

**Update:**

```
Employee::Employee(int id, const string& name, char gender, const Date& entry_date, string post, Department dept)
    : id(id), name(name), gender(gender), entry_date(entry_date), post(post), dept(dept){};
```

Comment: And it happens on the `new` expression? Not in the `Manager` or `Employee` constructors? That `new` expression is where the debugger stops?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I'm sure

Comment: My glass bowl is broken and I can't see any code which can cause a fault... if the question will not add some useful information, we should close it I believe... As others already mentioned: Use a debugger to see where the exception was thrown...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The new expression is where the debugger stops

Comment: You have at least 2 types we can't see the implementation of: `Date` and `Department`. They might throw, but we can't know it from your code

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik sry, Just updated it, please check

Comment: Can you also provide a minimal and reproducible code which results in the exception? The code provided alone is unlike to cause any problems.

Comment: In your `Manager` constructor, you initialize the `Employee` class using the `Employee::post` member variable. At that point in time `Employee::post` haven't been initialized yet, and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *likely* because you have *undefined behavior*.

With your `Manager` constructor definition:

```
Manager::Manager(int id, const string &name, char gender, const Date &entry_date, Department dept)
    : Employee(id, name, gender, entry_date, post, dept), num_staff(0), staffs(NULL) {}
```

you are first initializing the parent `Employee` class part, which is good. *But* when you do that, you pass the uninitilized `post` member variable as an argument to the `Employee` constructor.

Because `post` is uninitialized that will lead to the above mentioned undefined behavior.

This is exactly like initializing any variable with itself:

```
std::string post = post;  // Makes no sense, and leads to UB
```

---

As for how to solve this, that really depends on your requirements. A simple solution would be to pass an empty string instead:

```
Manager::Manager(int id, const string &name, char gender, const Date &entry_date, Department dept)
    : Employee(id, name, gender, entry_date, "", dept), num_staff(0), staffs(NULL) {}
```

If you enable more and extra warnings (for GCC and Clang I always recommend at least `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, for MSVC `/W4`) and treat them as errors you might even get a warning about using the uninitialized member variable.

I also suggest you make all member variables `private`.